# Mock method that is imported into the module under test

Tags: python, python-mock

Say I want to test this module:

```
import osutils

def check_ip6(xml):
  ib_output = osutils.call('iconfig ib0')
  # process and validate ib_output (to be unit tested)
  ...
```

This method is dependent on the environment, because it makes a System call (which expects a specific network interface), so its not callable on a testmachine.

I want to write a Unit test for that method which checks if the processing of ib_output works as expected. Therefore I want to mock `osutils.call` and let it just return testdata. What is the preferred way to do that? Do I have to do mocking or (monkey) patching?

Example test:

```
def test_ib6_check():
    from migration import check_ib6
    # how to mock os_utils.call used by the check_ib6-method?
    assert check_ib6(test_xml) == True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to do `from osutils import call` and then when patching things replace `yourmodule.call` with something else before calling `test_ib6_check`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that this has nothing to do with mocks, afaik I just need a monkey patch: I need to import and change the `osutils.call`-method and then import the method under test (and NOT the whole module, since it would then import the original call-method) afterwards. So this method will then use my changed call-method:

```
def test_ib6_check():
    def call_mock(cmd):
        return "testdata"    
    osutils.call = call_mock
    from migration import check_ib6
    # the check_ib6 now uses the mocked method
    assert check_ib6(test_xml) == True
```